# Wordpress Admin pages are not loading

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-admin

I'm a complete newbie on WordPress development. I recently developed a WordPress website on my local machine and hosted to a live server. The website works totally fine, but ever since I hosted, the admin panel is not loading up beyond the progress bar as shown in the pic.

I tried using the duplicator plugin for hosting to the live server and since it doesn't work as mentioned above I tried transferring all the files using FTP but the result was same. Can someone help me on this, please?

The website URL is www.manalodyfamily.com

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ne6Tf.png)

Comment: Open file `wp-config.php` and change `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` to `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` and then load the admin panel and see errors you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging deep found the issue on the Theme used (TESSERACT Theme). There were this line of code which was trying to open up a file,

```
$file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
        while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
            $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        }
```

Since the fopen() returned False, the loop went infinite, stopping all further loading of the page. I could solve it making a minor change

```
$file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
        if($file_handle)
            {
            while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
                $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
            }
        fclose($file_handle);
        }
```

PS: The hosting provider notified me about the size of website getting larger and larger day by day, where It had eaten up 16GB of space in place of 120MB actual required. This leads me tracking the error log and found the bug inside the theme.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in charset of db. Open wp-config.php file and just change charset to utf8 & comment the old one.

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

Thanks

Comment: Thaks for taking the time to reply. I tried changing the charset to utf8, But still, the problem persists.